How to create VeeValidate form context and defineFields from config prop
Nothing special here (passing in the formConfig as a prop to FormComponent:
<script setup>
import FormComponent from '@/components/FormComponent.vue'

const onSubmit = async function (values) {
  console.log('my form values', values)
}

const formConfig = {
  callback: onSubmit,
  fields: [
    [
      {
        name: 'email',
        label: 'Email',
        type: 'textInput',
        validation: string().required().email()
      }
    ]
  ]
}
</script>

<template>
  <FormComponent :config="formConfig"> </FormComponent>
</template>

This is where there is an issue (either in how I am creating the definedFields or how I am binding them to the template).  Using the syntax from the docs (const [email] = defineField('email') and passing email into the template works as expected.  As written, form validation/model binding does not seem to be working.
<script setup>

const props = defineProps({
  config: { type: Object, required: true }
})

// build validationSchema
let schemaConfig = {}
props.config.fields.forEach((row) => {
  row.forEach((element) => {
    schemaConfig[element.name] = element.validation
  })
})

// get form context (passing in valdiaton schema)
const { defineField, handleSubmit, values, errors } = useForm({
  validationSchema: schemaConfig
})

// output of this is [[fieldName, ComputedRefImpl]]
// ComputedRefImpl is = defineField('email')
let container = []
props.config.fields.forEach((row, rowIdx) => {
  container[rowIdx] = []
  row.forEach((field) => {
    const [tmp] = defineField(field.name)
    container[rowIdx].push([field.name, tmp])
  })
})

// register callback with handleSubmit
const onSubmit = handleSubmit(props.config.callback)
</script>


<template>
  <Form @submit="onSubmit">
    <!-- for each row in container -->
    <div class="row" v-for="formRow in container">
      <!-- for each field in row -->
      <div class="col" v-for="field in formRow">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <label>{{ field[0] }}</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <InputText :v-model="field[1]" />
            <small class="p-error">{{ errors[field[0]] }}</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="row mt-4">
      <AppButton label="Submit" severity="info" type="submit" />
    </div>
  </Form>
</template>

